# A file encrypted with openssl C API can't be decrypted by command line openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am using AES 256 cbc encryption. I can encrypt and successfully decrypt the file with openssl C API. However, when I try to use a command line to decrypt the file encrypted by C API, the decryption will provide wrong output.
Here is the command line I am using:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in ./input.bin -K "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff" -iv "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff" -nopad > output.txt
```

I run the command with and without –nopad option. Without this option I get error “digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt”. 
When I use C API I am using the same IV and Key:

```
unsigned char key[] = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff,
                       0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff };
unsigned char iv[] = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff };
```

Are command line encryption and C API encryption compatible? Or am I missing any optional argument in command line or settings in C API to make the encryption/decryption interoperable between command line and C API?
Thanks for help.

EDIT:
The input.bin contains this data (posted here in hex):

```
    02 d3 f8 94 e0 8c 82 ae e9 13 27 a7 e6 e3 b0 3d
24 2a ea 37 5a ff fe 1a fe ee 41 0d 81 54 fa 32
```

Comment: Can you post an example ciphertext from your C implementation with the key and IV used to encrypt? It could be a file format issue; the command-line tool supports extracting meta-data like a salt for key derivation from the input file.

Comment: I have edited the question and posted the content of the file

Comment: Is the "vtPJd&" part of your plaintext?

Comment: The plain (and expected) text is "very short123456". I get this string when using openssl C API.

Comment: For that key and IV, with no padding, the cipher text should be `2ec58c22b1ecfcbfecdc114e1282f17b` (hex). The padding of 0x10 bytes would encrypt to `f13a128c2fd85d1f0e2f13ce22550285`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is actually encrypted in ECB mode .. i just decryped with an online tool:

```
76 65 72 79 20 73 68 6f 72 74 31 32 33 34 35 36  very short123456
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Comment: OMG. Yes. Thanks. What online tool did you use?